# Why {{#if isDirty}} not working as expected with Ember Model? ( with JSBin )

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I'm trying to get my template to display a save button when the form is changed.

The when the value of an input field is changed, the model is set to isDirty=true, but template tag is not activated.

**Pertinent Information**

- Using Ember Model ( not Ember Data )
- Edit route is nested in item route
- Model is being set to isDirty = true ( I think I'm not binding to it correctly )

[image]

**JSBin with prototype of the problem**

http://jsbin.com/owanef/19/edit

If you click on Edit, you will see edit form for the active model. When I enter anything into the field, the model doesn't become dirty or it doesn't propagate to the template.

What could be causing this?

**Summary**

Ember Model doesn't bind isDirty to the controller. As a result, controller's isDirty property is update correctly, but model's is not. Read more about this in [Github Issue](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/194).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the ember-model included to use the version on github master, and now it shows `isDirty` to be true always. See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovapok/2) using master.

This may be a bug in Ember-model. You may want to file an issue on github.

Comment: Yeah, it looks related to https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/pull/168 and https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/65 I'm trying to figure out what the resolution for this is. Thank you for looking into this.